# jquery.min.js vs jquery-n.nn.n.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to run the demo for [bootstrap-timepicker](https://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/), the demoe references 
jquery.min.js but from the JQuery download I got jquery-1.12.4.min.js .

What is the process in this case, is it to be understood to download the latest version and rename it to jquery.min.js or to change the reference from jquery.min.js to jquery-1.12.4.min.js.

I know using Bower would automagically get everything is needed but 1.My companies proxy settings was causing bower to time out and 2.Just want to know why a demo that is most likely is used by many correctly is pointing to a file that is not downloadable manually from JQuery site

Comment: Wow, voting to close because it is obvious to you? What am I missing here that makes this not a question for likes of you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do whatever you want in your own server. Keeping the version number will allow you to download multiple versions, in case your applications have version dependencies. If you rename it to `jquery.min.js` then you need to be very careful about upgrading it, because it could potentially break some applications if there's an incompatible change in the new version.

The demo probably doesn't use a version number because they didn't want readers to think it was dependent on a specific version.

Comment: "The demo probably doesn't use a version number because they didn't want readers to think it was dependent on a specific version." thank you for that, being a javascript quamby I wouldnt be able to think of that.